# jQuery setInterval isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var interval = setInterval("change_height()", 500);
    var height;

    function change_height() {
        height = parseInt(window.location.hash);
        $('#message_body').height(height);
        alert("");
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
});
```

for some reason the change_height() function just isn't being called yet it works if I put it outside the document.ready block but then the clearInterval doesn't work!

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You should try putting the 'interval' var AND the 'change_height' function outside of the 'document.ready'

Comment: It does not work because `change_height` is only local to the `ready` event handler, but the string passed to `setInterval` is evaluated in the global scope. Pass the function reference directly, as @Alexander suggests. Another question: Why do you use `setInterval` if you clear it after the first execution? A simple `setTimeout` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setInterval is a native javascript function and not a jQuery function.

With that cleared up, try just referencing the function directly using:

```
var interval = setInterval(change_height, 500);
    // Note the lack of () which would execute the function
```

This is better than letting the setInterval function interpret the string.

Comment: +1 It's not only better, it is the way to make it work. It's a scope issue.

Comment: Your comment got me curious, it can indeed be quickly explained to the following:
`setInterval('change_height()',500);` would be evaluated to call a function of `window.change_height()`, however, this function does not exist. Another possible fix could then be to move the change_height() over to the global scope however this is bad practice and should be avoided. Using the `setInterval(change_height,500)` as it was intended is the better of the two solutions.

Comment: Exactly. Also avoids global namespace pollution. There is never a reason to pass a string to these methods... I wonder who down voted your answer though :-/ (and why).

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var interval = setInterval(function() { change_height(); }, 500);
    var height;

    function change_height() {
        height = parseInt(window.location.hash);
        $('#message_body').height(height);
        alert("");
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont pass strings to setInterval, pass the function reference:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var interval;
    var height;

    function change_height() {
        height = parseInt(window.location.hash);
        $('#message_body').height(height);
        alert("");
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    interval = setInterval(change_height, 500);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code sample:

```
var intervalId;

$(document).ready(function () {
    intervalId = window.setInterval('sample.func1();', 500);
});

var sample = {
    func1: function () {
        alert('test 1');
        window.clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices:

1) Remove the parenthesis and quotes from `setInterval`:

```
setInterval(change_height, 500);
```

OR
2) Declare your function as global:

```
window.change_height = function() {
    height = parseInt(window.location.hash);
    $('#message_body').height(height);
    alert("");
    clearInterval(interval);
}
```

This is because when you were using `"change_height()"`, `setInterval` was looking a global function, but your function was local.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use settimeout. Because setinterval executes regardless of the code is finished. 
And call the settimeout from the last line in your function.

```
setTimeOut("change_height", 500);
```